# ropemacs on windows with django project is very slow

Tags: python, django, windows, emacs, ropemacs

In a newly created Django project I'm using ropemacs to get semantic completions and refactoring functionality. But it seems that everytime I enter a character that triggers a completion list check, the buffer freezes for about a second, sometimes two.

I heard that ropemacs can be slow on big projects, but is a fresh Django project considered big in this respect?

I'm using YAS, rope, autocomplete and python-mode (https://launchpad.net/python-mode). In the modes section i have "Py Outl yas Rope AC", not exactly sure where Outl came from or what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i wrote in the comments and as David said, I resorted to using Jedi.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1092841

please follow here, maybe we need some more info when digging into

Comment: thank you! unfortunately I changed to emacs-jedi for now, but I will follow the thread there and do what I can to help if needed

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi)!

It's faster than rope and understands your Python code much better.

May the force be with you!